# Excel PivotTable based on cube - how to split measures based on two members of a dimension

Tags: excel, pivot, mdx, cube

My cube has a Sales value.

Also an Item dimension.  Members of Item hierarchy are 'Cat1' and 'Cat2'.  Cat1 and Cat2 can each have a variety of different values.

**I am trying to define a member based on specific values for Cat1 and Cat2.**

The new member will be used in the PivotTable Columns to split Sales by the new member.

```
"1Cup" where Cat1 = Coffee and Cat2 IN (Cup,Cup1)
"OtherCoffee" where Cat1 = Coffee and Cat2 IN (Creamer,Accessory,Box)
"AllOtherSales" Cat1 = OPS and Cat2 IN (Accessory,Battery,Electronics...and on and on)
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that `Item` is the name of the hierarchy and `Cat1` and `Caz2` are levels of that hierarchy? And that you want to create the member in the cube, not in Excel, i. e. you have the possibility to change the cube?

Comment: I cannot modify the cube so I need to do this in Excel.  Item is the hierarchy and Cat1 and Cat2 are levels.  Within Cat1 and Cat2 are members that I need to combine (via formula?) into a "super" Category that varies with the Cat1 and Cat2 combination.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the cube, then there is no easy possibility to create calculated memebrs, except - according to [this blog post](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2012/10/15/calculated-member-and-measures-in-excel-2013.aspx), if you have Excel 2013. In older Excel versions, the only possibility I know would be to install the [OLAP Pivot Table extensions](http://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/), a plugin for Excel that allows you to add MDX calculated measures which you can then use in the query.

Assuming you have one of these possibilities to write MDX member definitions, and assuming your `Item` hierarchy is in dimension `Dim` and 'Cat1' and `Cat2` are levels, the attributes on which they are based are named 'Cat1' and `Cat2` as well, and the members you want to define should be located in the top level, just below the `All` member, which I assume is called `All` (you see I have to assume a lot of details about your cube and your requirements), the MDX would be as follows:

For the **`1Cup`** member, the member name would be `[Dim].[Item].[All].[1Cup]`, and the definition would be

```
Aggregate({ [Dim].[Cat1].[Coffee] } * { [Dim].[Cat2].[Cup], [Dim].[Cat2].[Cup1] })
```

and similar for the other members, each new name you want to use will be a separate member.
 attribute, the MDX to define your member would be something like